# High Availability

Tags: advantage-database-server

Has anyone setup Advantage Database Server using a failover cluster? If so, did it work and do you have any tips or tricks that you can share?

Answer (score 1):

Advantage supports fault tolerance within a Windows Cluster. It does not currently support load balancing.

Advantage works in both Windows 2003 and Windows 2008 clusters. Use these links to get more information about setting up Advantage in a [Windows 2003](http://blog.advantageevangelist.com/2009/03/configure-advantage-on-windows-2003.html).

Comment: Here is a link for a [Windows 2008](http://blog.advantageevangelist.com/2009/03/configure-advantage-on-windows-2008.html) cluster.